# How to include test assemblies in a published artifact?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

I have an Asp.Net Core web app.  Under the same solution as this web app are two additional projects; a .net core class library, and that class library's related test project.

I'm experimenting with Azure pipelines, and have created a pipeline which successfully builds and tests my code.  However, I want to use the output from this build pipeline as a feed to my release pipeline, which is associated with a `test plan` with some `test case`s linked to automated unit tests (I don't actually have anywhere to release to; the release pipeline is solely to allow the test plan to be run).

My release pipeline takes the artifacts published by the build pipeline as input.  However, this only includes those DLLs required for the web app; not the related test assemblies.

I suspect that I could work around this by adding the test project as a dependency of the web app, but that's clearly wrong.  I'm hoping there's a way to create a separate artifact, or subfolder within the artifact to include my test assemblies so that they've available to the release pipeline's tests.

The pipeline definitions are too long to include in this post, but I've made them available on [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/JohnLBevan/667e1686960d8c2f3f1a74882d0659e7).

Comment: Why do you want to use a release definition if you're not releasing anything? You can run a test plan from a build definition.

Comment: @DanielMann When experimenting with the test framework it wouldn't allow me to manually invoke a test run which included a test case connected to my unit tests until a "validating phase" existed.  The test run properties show this as being under a release pipeline ([screenshot of release properties](https://i.imgur.com/DITsUOj.png)).  This differs from the screenshot in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=vsts

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I seem to be running into the exact same problem